# Detect FingerPrint Scanner touch or move

Tags: java, android, android-fingerprint-api

I was trying to get some documentation or some kind of information about android fingerprint scanner. But I can find only the [authentication](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#fingerprint-authentication) api only. But clearly pixels has a swipe function on touch sensor and I found some xda developer also got [that working](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-fingerprint-to-unlock-t3466549)  . But I can't find any docs where I can find info that detect a touch or move in a touch sensor.

PS : I don't have any code yet, I was trying to grab the info and then start working on my idea.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no APIs for the fingerprint sensors beyond the authentication APIs. Touch and swipe gestures are controlled solely at the system level.